# How can I test sprite collision in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, collision

How do I start to implement a class for sprite collision?

Answer (score 6):

As Eric pointed out, CGRectIntersectsRect is the method to test two bounding rects for overlapping. Use the boundingBox method of the CCNode classes to get the correct bounding box for each sprite (or other node).

See my answer here:
[Collision Detection in Cocos2d game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353008/collision-detection-in-cocos2d-game/4353251)

Answer (score 2):

I would look into `b2ContactListener`

You can do some searches on that, and you'll easily get some results

Comment: I believe this is apart of box2d which is apart of Cocos2d.  Might help with your searches.

Comment: box2d is a physics engine.  Can be too much for just collision detection

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform very simple collision detecting by checking if two rectangles intersect.  You can use the CGRectIntersectsRect function to do this.  Basically, both rects are based on the position and dimensions of sprites you want to check for collisions.  If CGRectIntersectsRect returns true, you know a collision occurred.

More info here: [http://icodeblog.com/2009/02/18/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-2-user-interaction-simple-ai-game-logic/][1]

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [chipmunk's physics engine](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/), which is part of the cocos2d engine.

[Example (iPhone)](http://iphonedev.net/2009/05/10/cocos2d-example-bouncing-ball/)

Comment: for "simple" collision detection you don't need a physics engine, that's overkill.